# Updated Android Studio now my app crashes with errors I have never seen

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I recently updated Android Studio but after updating the app crashes when trying to open it.

Could someone please help me fix the app?

Here are the error messages:

```
    1412-1412/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
06-25 13:31:09.047 2428-2720/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
06-25 13:31:09.049 1412-5345/? I/AudioFlinger: AudioFlinger’s thread 0xa4303d40 ready to run
06-25 13:31:09.050 2428-2720/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
06-25 13:31:09.050 2428-2720/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
06-25 13:31:09.050 2428-2720/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@a2292b5
06-25 13:31:09.053 2428-2720/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
```

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**

I read somewhere I had to add this to my manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />` and now I have an error for java.lang.NumberFormatException: for Input stain: "0:010". never had problems until this update :/

Comment: This is not the error you should be looking at, filter for your own app's package name

Comment: how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Android made some changes. The gradle file will no longer use compile terminology. Implementation will be used instead of compile. I suggest you change compile terms with implemention. Finally, if the problem is not solved, you can update your libraries. I hope I could help...

Comment: everything is using implementation... still nothing, This is so weird. I read somewhere I had to add this to my manifest: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />  and now I have an error for java.lang.NumberFormatException: for Input stain: "0:010". never had problems until this update :/

Comment: Record Audio
API 16 and above versions should be allowed in dialogue.
Do you do this?

Comment: I just added that based on someone else's problem I saw on Stack. and my min SDK is 20 so it should be good

Comment: Can you chehk your app permission on your phone?

Comment: what do you mean? what permissions are we talking about? I am using an emulator. I think right now the problem is what I put on my edit: the java.lang.NumberFormatException